# How do I consume the bytes of xhr.responseText?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I'd like to download a 400+ mb Json file using xmlhttprequest, but the immense size of the file causes chrome to throw an Ah Snap message.

I know I can use something like setInterval() to read the response text as it is streamed, but how do I consume it after each call to setInterval?

Or do I just need to use a different web protocol altogether?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably better off splitting the file into pieces, or have a serverside solution sending you pieces of the file. Each browser will have its own limit on how much it can handle, but alas it's more in the 40Mb to 100Mb range than 400Mb+.

I found this link: http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000545/ch15.html#XHR_STREAMING that describes a method to 'fake' streaming text with xhr, but it mentions it's rather slow, so it might not fit your requirements.